# Question about list(queryset)

Tags: django

If i'm making:

```
queryset=User.objects.all()
lst=list(queryset)
```

then

```
print lst[2].first_name
```

does it takes the `first_name` of second element from database or from memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `list(queryset)` it will evaluate the query in the database and store it in memory.  So the `print[2].first_name` will not hit the db again, but rather pull it from that in-memory list.

Comment: @Pol: If you think about it, it can't do anything else. Once you've called `list` on it, it's no longer a queryset - it's a list. And lists don't know anything about databases.

Comment: But iside of list there is User instances. And user instances it is inherited objects of Model class. And model class has a lot of relation with database.

Comment: Yes, but a model doesn't actually know anything about the database either, in fact. A model is populated from the db, by the queryset, and knows how to save itself back, but isn't related to it in any other way.